# Specified module could not be found (uninstall) (2)

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I have a program I need to uninstall. Every time I try to do it from the control panel, it says the following:

> RunDLL
>   There was a problem starting C:\Program
>   The specified module could not be found

I have tried the explanation in this link:

[Specified module could not be found (uninstall)](https://superuser.com/questions/423922/specified-module-could-not-be-found-uninstall?answertab=votes#tab-top)

The same problem exists, no matter what I do. Can anyone help me?

Here is the name of the uninstall string:

> RunDll32 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\INSTAL~1\PROFES~1\RunTime\10\00\Intel32\Ctor.dll,LaunchSetup "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information{3F15DF4D-DCA2-4995-BD65-4A56322C180B}\setup.exe" -l0x9  -removeonly

Nothing changed, original file name. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It appears its hitting the space after the first "c:\program" and thinking the next word(s) are additional arguments.

Try putting quotes around the first path:

`RunDll32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\INSTAL~1\PROFES~1\RunTime\10\00\Intel32\Ctor.dll,LaunchSetup" "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information{3F15DF4D-DCA2-4995-BD65-4A56322C180B}\setup.exe" -l0x9 -removeonly`

Comment: Cool, I think it helped, new problem comes up now though.

"You do not have sufficient access to uninstall TrueColorFinder Software. Please contact you administrator."

I am new with Windows 7, so I assume it is not similar to Vista were you have to open everything as admin.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: Open a command prompt "As Administrator" and run the above command again.